# Ajax in Codeigniter doesn't work for a specific controller in remote host

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery, codeigniter-2

My web application does Ajax request to a Codeigniter-php code in a remote server. It works in localhost but not with a specific controller in remote host. It is strange because works in localhost for both controllers.
The request:

```
$.ajax({
    async:true,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",  
    url:"/CI/site/index.php/contact/submitContact",
    data: "", //data example 
    success:arrived,
    error:problems }); 

function arrived(data){
    var dataJson = eval(data);                       
}
function problems(){            
    $("#result").text('Problems.');     
}
```

I check the arrived with `log_message`. With the next function works fine:

```
  function submitContact(){
     log_message('error', 'submitContact. ');
    //If data are received
    if($_POST){
            log_message('error', 'data. [application/controllers/contact.php]');
        }   
    }
```

However, If I change the request to `url:"/CI/site/index.php/control/controlHome"`, there isn't any log message and the output is the next:
 `POST http://www.page.com/CI/site/index.php/control/controlHome 500 (Internal Server Error)`

The function `/application/controllers/control.php` is the next:

```
 function controlHome(){
    log_message('error', 'controlHome. [application/controllers/control.php]');
    //If data are received
    if($_POST){
         log_message('error', 'data. [application/controllers/control.php]');
    }   
 }
```

Also I've tried with complete url in the ajax code but the result is the same. Any setting is required?

Comment: You set csrf protection true ? That's cause problem with Ajax.

Comment: I've set csrf protection true, but I obtain the same error

Comment: Try with csrf false for testing. When open directly from browser "/CI/site/index.php/contact/submitContact" you get same 500 error ?

Comment: Yes. The same error. I tried with true and false for testing. Then is not an Ajax problem. is not?

Comment: That's true, not an Ajax problem. Control.PHP starts with <?php class Control extends CI_Controller {

Comment: Yes, `<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); class Control extends CI_Controller{` I'm very surprised

Comment: You can see it [here](http://www.domoticamadrid.eu/control.txt)

Comment: That's seems no syntax error. Maybe a bit later I can check more carefully. Gangway library works properly ? Maybe that cause problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this AJAX csrf protection with codeigniter 2. This solve my same problem

http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20

UPDATE:
I checked your control.php file on my test server.

```
if($_POST) { /* i only commented gangway library functions  */
} else { /* only replace the load->view with an print_r $data; and its work */ }
```

And put to comment the gangway library on construct. And control/controlHome works normaly without any error. Check your gangway library THAT's cause error 500.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the problem is the hosting. Now, doesn't work the ajax request that before worked. I'll speak with the hosting provider

Comment: Turn `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` and open the ajax called controller in your browser, if you get an Internal server error 500 something wrong with the code, but if you can't get an error the problem in the ajax call. Or try to contact with the hosting provider.

Comment: I've solved it, the problem was in another library code that gangway library used. Thanks for you time.